# HTTPS web application to communicate with a changing set of WebSocket servers

Tags: https, websocket, ssl-certificate, activemq-classic

I have a web application that manages a dynamically changing set of servers. The web application communicates with the servers via WebSockets. On the servers WebSockets are provided by ActiveMQ.

Everything works well via HTTP and WS.

However, once I switch the web application to use HTTPS (with a proper certificate), the WebSocket communication doesn't work, since it is not secured. It would need to be WSS.

As mentioned, at any given point in time, I have many different servers, and they keep changing too, so I can't statically configure the certificates for the WSS connections. I would need an automated and scalable solution.

Apart from having a wildcard certificate covering all subdomains of my domain name, and assigning a subdomain to every server by programmatically updating DNS records, is there any easier/better solution?

Setting up a WSS to WS proxy on a separate server could also be a way, however that doesn't seem like a good/scalable solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, this was the solution:

> [...] having a wildcard certificate covering all subdomains of my
>   domain name, and assigning a subdomain to every server by
>   programmatically updating DNS records [...]

DNS A records immediately take effect, so as long as an A record with a unique subdomain name is created for every new server/IP, it will work.
One thing to consider is if the provider has any limitations on the number of DNS records.